# WPF use static resource in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control defines in my `Application.Resources` and want to use it as a DataTemplate for a ComboBox.

The user control:

```xml
<TextBlock 
   x:Key="ListItemView"
   Text="{Binding Name}"
   ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
```

The Combox Box in my Window:

```xml
<ComboBox 
   ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"
   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <!-- TODO how to use StaticResource ListItemView in here? -->
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You must put your user control into DataTemplate

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItemView">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                  ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
2. Use your data template

   ```
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItemView}">
   </ComboBox>
   ```